# Page redirect not working after loading content from SQL Database

Tags: php, sql, redirect, header, whitespace

I'm building an online commerce webpage.  I have a 'check_inventory.php' page and I'm having an issue where after I query the page, I get all the data and all is good.  But when I click a link to go to another page or to delete an item..., any link actually, I'm getting an error.

**Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.**

I think it might have something to do with the `header( )` redirect function or something with the white space.  I've gotten rid of all the white spaces ...  But I still get the same issues. I'm really not sure what could cause this.

Any ideas would be helpful.

Comment: post your code `ROSS
`

Comment: the redirect need to be the first line on the page in order to work

Comment: Here is the code...  take a look and see if you can figure out anything.  Something else came to my attention.  It seems that my session variable might be getting destroyed somehow after the data is output to the screen.  Its really crazy.

Comment: <?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["manager"])){
 header("location: admin_login.php");
 exit();
}
// Be sure to check that this manager SESSION value is in fact in the database
$id = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i','', $_SESSION["id"]);  // filter everything but numbers and letters
$password = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_SESSION["password"]);
$manager = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_SESSION["manager"]);

Comment: // connect to MySQL Database
include_once("../store_scripts/xyz_conct_2_mysqli.php");
//Run MySQL query to be sure that this person is  
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `admin` WHERE `id`='$id' AND `username`='$manager' AND `password`='$password'  LIMIT 1";
$query = mysqli_query($db_linkconx, $sql  );
// -------- MAKE SURE PERSON IS IN DATABASE ---------
$existCount = mysqli_num_rows($query); // count the row number
if($existCount == 0) { // evaluate the count
 echo "Your login session data is not on record in the database.";
 //header("location: indexx.php");
 exit();
}
?>

Comment: <?php
if(isset($_POST['submit3'])) 
{
$product_list = "";  
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `products` ORDER BY date_added ASC";
$query = mysqli_query($db_linkconx, $sql  );
$productCount = mysqli_num_rows($query);  // count the output amount
 if($productCount > 0 ) 
 {
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query) ) 
  {

Comment: $id = $row["id"];
   $date_added = strftime("%b %d, %Y", strtotime($row["date_added"]));
   $product_name = $row["product_name"];
   $price = $row["price"];
   $details = $row["details"];
   $product_list .= "<b>ID#:</b>$id&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>NAME:</b>$product_name&nbsp;&nbsp|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
           <b>DATE:</b> $date_added &nbsp;&nbsp|&nbsp;<b>PRICE:</b>$price &nbsp;&nbsp;&emsp;&emsp;<br />
           <b>DETAILS:</b>$details<br />
           <a href='inventory_edit.php?pid=$id#'>edit</a>&nbsp;&bull; 
           <a href='inventory_list.php?deleteid=$id'>delete</a><br />";}}

Comment: Sorry this text editor won't allow for all the code to be placed properly.  This was the best I could do.  I also have the HTML but I figure this might be enough if you paste it into notepad++ or some other code editor.

Answer (score 0):

You can eventually try redirecting through JS:

```
echo "<script>window.location = 'yourpage.php';</script>";
```